# iPhone sdk UILabel color not changing when re-launching application

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, uicolor

I have tableview in that I used `UILabel` to display the list of books. Also I have a `UIButton` to download the books in that tableview. After downloading those books I need change the label color into gray color from black color. Now am able to change the `UILabel` color after downloading the book. But when am re-launching the application, it returns to normal mode (i.e) text color is in black color.

Here is my code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) 
   {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   } 

   if(appDelegate.fontFlag==1 && [[databaseArray valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
    {
        //appDelegate.fontFlag=0;
        NSString *cellValue = [listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//[downlodedBooksArray objectAtIndex:appDelegate.databaseIndex];
        Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        NSLog(@"cellValuebluecolor%@",cellValue);
        [Label setText:cellValue];


    }
    else
    {

    NSString *cellValue = [listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [Label setText:cellValue];

    //  cell.text = cellValue;
    Label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }

    Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Label];

return cell;
}
```

Why this happens? or How should I change my code even after re-launching my app to get the specified color only if downloaded?

Comment: A few questions: Where does `Label` come from? Is the `Label` part of the cell?

Comment: Instead of cell.textlabel i added an uilabel.

Comment: Yes but then after you dequeue a cell, you need to access this `UILabel` IN the cell somehow like `cell.yourUILabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];` - It seems that you're accessing the wrong `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

After your books are downloaded save a value in preferences. Use this value to check conditions every time. This way you can maintain the color of your label even when you re-launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to save this in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in `NSUserDefault` and when you want to check that its downloaded at that time retrive the array from userdefault and check from this.. see the example of `NSUserDefault` ...

In `AppDelegate.h` file just declare variable...

```
NSUserDefaults  *userDefaults;
NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

after...

In `AppDelegate.m` Fille in `applicationDidFinishLonching:` Method

```
userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
    if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [yourArray retain];
```

after that when you want to insert Data in this UserDefaults Use Bellow Code...

```
[appDelegate.yourArray addObject:yourDataString];///set your value or anything which you want to store here...
NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:appDelegate.yourArray];
[appDelegate.userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourArray"];
[appDelegate.userDefaults synchronize];
```

**AND** check that with bellow condition with your code , i just put the userdefault array here..

```
if(appDelegate.fontFlag==1 && [[appDelegate.yourArray valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
    {
        //appDelegate.fontFlag=0;
        NSString *cellValue = [listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//[downlodedBooksArray objectAtIndex:appDelegate.databaseIndex];
        Label.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        NSLog(@"cellValuebluecolor%@",cellValue);
        [Label setText:cellValue];
    }
```

i hope this help you...